# Disable or delete cache - twigphp/cache-extra

Tags: laravel, caching, twig, twig-extension

I’ve implemented twigbridge in Laravel 10+ as my template system. It works well on its own, but I wanted a little extra control over caching processor intensive actions via the templates themselves using the {% cache %} tag. So I installed [twigphp/cache-extra](https://github.com/twigphp/cache-extra) and configured that. It works as intended, but now I need to know a little more about it since there is VERY little documentation about it. Specifically how to clear/clean the cache on demand.

1. **Cache Storage** - unlike the twig view cache which defaults to /storage/framework/views/twig, I cannot find where or how cache-extra stores its cache. It’s not the same folder because deleting those files has no effect. Where and how is this stored? Is there a way to configure storage path yourself?
2. **Cache-extra disabling** - Twig view caching can be disabled using twigbridge.php  `cache => false`, but I see no reference anywhere to disabling cache-extra. Is this possible, and if so, how?
3. **Cache-extra cleaning** - The [cache-extra documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/cache.html) states two ways of invalidating cached values - using ttl() or using a cache-buster variable in the key. It does not say anything about whether these invalidated caches are auto-cleaned or whether they simply stay in the repository indefinitely. Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: For now I am just going to use a site-wide cache-buster variable and use the {%cache%} tag sparingly, but it is highly inconvenient during development to not be able to disable the cache or clear it with a command. However, it is too valuable an extension not to use, so I may do some digging and even fork it if I have to.